# You only seem to notice me

Tags: word-usage, usage

The entire class was talking. But the teacher started yelling at just one girl for talking during class. She seemed to yell at only her each day, as if she was holding some kind of grudge against her. So she just blew up at the teacher one day:

> **You only seem to notice me**. It's as if I'm the only one talking here. You're always yelling at me, and only me. Well, news flash! I'm not the only one talking.

Does this sound fine? And this has actually happened. Can it be more natural? Does the bold phrase sound fine?

Answer (score 1):

It's natural and it's understandable from the context. *Only* is a tricky modifier and its placement can cause ambiguity. Here are the possible meanings depending on where the word appears in the sentence:

> **Only** you seem to notice me.
>   (Everybody else ignores me.)
>
> You **only** seem to notice me.
>   (You're pretending to notice me.)
>
> You seem **only** to notice me. You seem to **only** notice me.
>   (You don't pay any meaningful attention to me.)
>
> You seem to notice **only** me. You seem to notice me **only**.
>   (No one else draws your attention.)

Again, that last is what was meant, particularly given the girl's likely tone and emphasis. Context is everything.

Comment: So does it sound wrong in the context of my post?

Comment: What about: It's as if I'm the only one you seem to notice.

Comment: In most cases, *only* modifies by proximity, so in your example just above,*only* modifies *one*, which is what the girl meant.